# Automating Web Package Deployment

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, tfs, msdeploy

My company uses VS2012 for web development, ADFS2.0 for identity management, and various database setups. Right now, we have multiple branches for web: dev, test, and prod. What we want to do is have a system in place that fully automates deployment from TFS to our dev/test/prod environments, a sort of one click process that will kick off a build, and then deploy the build to the proper environment. I have looked at MSDeploy, along with some others, but we are limited on what we can use because of security/legal reasons. Is there any way to get this done? I will explain a bit further:

We have a share on our network that holds "master" copies of each environment(dev, test, prod). People work on code locally on their machines from the dev environment, then when done, they check it in to the dev environment. We currently have to manually kick off a build(which I know can be automated), then we have to let our admins know to deploy that to the right spots on the servers(which I know can also be automated). Is there a way to set up some sort of hook to automatically deploy builds that have been kicked off?

Answer (score 0):

You can try commercial options like http://octopusdeploy.com/ or http://www.red-gate.com/delivery/deployment-manager/ or http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/inrelease/ ( soon to be integrated with tfs) otherwise you can achieve the same with MS deploy and powershellscript which needs more development time.

Comment: have you any experiences using one of them?
Could you share how you are organising deploys?